# Codesigning iOS applications (APNS Enabled) without using XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, code-signing

I want to build a single window Mac application, which can be used to codesign iOS applications without using XCode.

Many of our clients use "Enterprise License" to distribute their apps. Each year they need to be resigned and its a repetitive work. Their requirements are following

1. Apps make use of APNS
2. They don't want to share their Enterprise License
3. Bundle identifier should be replaceable while signing with their certificate
4. They have certificates with same name in Keychain

Userinterface has the following fields

1. Path to the *.ipa file
2. Path to the *.mobileprovision file
3. Keychain name (optional incase more than one certificate with same name exists)
4. Name of the certificate (iPhone Developer : .....)

I was **able to codesign** application, but **APNS is not working after resigning**. Or is it not possible to resign applications making use of bundleIdentifier?

And also I would like to add a feature of drop down list of certificates available in Keychain for improved useability. Any pointers would be great help

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Is it possible to codesign applications making use of APNS without using XCode?

Comment: You can code sign through the command line, but trust me, you don't want to.

Comment: No its not by command line, I'm trying to use the inbuild codesign tool, Use it via NSTask and providing a very simple UI. I was able to resign applications which can be installed in iOS Devices. The issue is with Push Notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable push notifications, the app ID and provisioning profile will need to have that configured and allowed by Apple (through the portal). You can't enable it for arbitrary provisioning profiles/apps just by resigning.

During codesigning, the entitlements need to have the `apns-environment` key set to `sandbox`/`production` depending on what the app uses. This will then be verified at runtime by iOS. If you are using a third-party signing tool, it *should* take the `apns-environment` value from the provisioning profile.

For debugging, you can look at the entitlements for a .app with this command:

```
codesign -d --requirements - --entitlements - path/to/My.app
```

You should see an `apns-environment` value, but only if the provisioning profile had that enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you mentioned the AppId and mobileprovision is configured as per the standards. The requirement is to resign with a valid mobileprovision that may or may not have the same appId as the previous one. So If I can take the appid and entitlements from my mobileprovision, and provide it to codesign task. The app should be successfully codesigned, isn't it?

Comment: It should work, yes. We do this kind of thing a lot with in-house scripts we've developed. You essentially need to update Info.plist (with the new app id), the entitlements (via codesigning) and the embedded.mobileprovision inside the app. As long as that is all done correctly it should work.

Comment: That's great, infact I did the same independently. I extracted the plist from mobileprovision extracted the application-identifier and then made a copy of info.plist and then changed the CFBundleIdentifier and used the entitlements info to codesign the application. It now works, but it all seemed very hackish. I have accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: It may seem hackish, but you can automate the whole process with the right scripts and tools. The process is all perfectly legit, and is exactly what Xcode will be doing when it codesigns your apps. Although Xcode interestingly doesn't modify the entitlements.

Comment: If I'm not asking too much, can you point me to any valid links to a coderesign tool.

Comment: Sorry; all I know of is what I developed for my employers, and I can't release that openly.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent several hours researching this same issue and discovered the following process. Taking Mike's comments one step further, providing the following command line for others running into the same issue.

I am starting with an xcode release build using a bundle id that has been configured for production push notification.

From the terminal window run the following commands - replacing the "CAPITAL SECTIONS" with your info

```
codesign -d --entitlements -"NAME OF APP.app" > entitlements.plist

codesign -f -s "SIGNING CERTIFICATE NAME" --resource-rules "NAME OF APP.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements entitlements.plist "NAME OF APP.app"
```

Hope this helps the next person struggling with this same issue